# Error with validator (No validator could be found for type: java.util.Date.)

Tags: hibernate

My friends,

I have class with ...

```
@NotBlank(message = "timesheet.cadastro.horainicio.obrigatorio")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@Column(name = "INICIO", nullable = false)
private Date horaInicio;
```

And, in my test (groovy) I put null to "horaInicio" :

```
def "Salvar um timesheet sem hora inicio"() {
    given:"um timesheet sem data"
        def usuario = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Usuario.class,1L) as Usuario
        def dias = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Dias.class,1L) as Dias
        def timeSheet = criarTimeSheet(usuario,dias) as TimeSheet
        timeSheet.horaInicio = null
    when:"buscar na base"
        def timeSheetPersistido = timeSheetService.salvar(timeSheet)
    then:"retorna uma lista de timesheet"
        def erro = thrown(ConstraintViolationException)
        "timesheet.cadastro.horainicio.obrigatorio".equals(erro.getConstraintViolations().asList().get(0).getMessage())
}
```

but I have error:

```
Expected exception javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException, but got javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.thrownImpl(SpecInternals.java:79)
    at br.com.infowhere.service.TimeSheetServiceIt.Salvar um timesheet sem hora inicio(TimeSheetServiceIt.groovy:80)
Caused by: javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.util.Date.
```

Anybody can help me ?

thanks

Answer (score 38):

As also said in documentation, [@NotBlank](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotBlank.html) is for String type. There is no concept of java.util.Date being blank. It can be null or not null.

> Validate that the annotated string is not null or empty. The
>   difference to NotEmpty is that trailing whitespaces are getting
>   ignored.

If goal is to check is value not null, [@NotNull](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) should be used. According documentation:

> The annotated element must not be null. Accepts any type.

Comment: I put @NotNull but don't work :-(    @NotNull(message = "timesheet.cadastro.horainicio.obrigatorio")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    @Column(name = "INICIO", nullable = false)
    private Date horaInicio;

Comment: hi my friend, I'm sorry, It's work now ! I had another atribute that I hadn't changed ;-) thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Temporal(DATE)
@Column(name = "creation_timestamp")
private Date creationTimestamp;
```

or

```
@Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "creation_timestamp")
private Date creationTimestamp;
```

if db type is 'datetime'.

Simple and it works. no extra @annotations needed.

Answer (score -2):

juste delete `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)`
 annotation ;-)

Comment: Why ? Explain. Regards.

Comment: depends on db, why mysql removing @Temporal will work with a util.Date.