# javax.servlet.ServletException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.util.Date

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jboss, annotations

The exception on title appears when I submit a form using JSF 2.1 and using JBoss server.

I'm trying to use and learn hibernate annotations.

My Entity bean is as this :

```
@NotEmpty
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;
```

I'm getting this error page :

```
JBWEB000071: root cause

javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.util.Date.
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConstraintTree.verifyResolveWasUnique(ConstraintTree.java:411)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConstraintTree.findMatchingValidatorClass(ConstraintTree.java:392)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConstraintTree.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintTree.java:350)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:171)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConstraintTree.validateComposingConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:259)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:154)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:124)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:86)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validatePropertyForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:820)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validatePropertyForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:733)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateValueInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:690)
    org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateValue(ValidatorImpl.java:169)
    javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.validate(BeanValidator.java:315)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:1153)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:971)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1237)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:702)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1216)
    javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1216)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1216)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1164)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
```

Does somebody knows why ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Even if I don't understand the similarities between `@NotEmpty` and `@NotBlank`, this post works for me :

[Error with validator (No validator could be found for type: java.util.Date.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555734/error-with-validator-no-validator-could-be-found-for-type-java-util-date)

Regards,

**Edit:**

Even if I got the remark of duplicated question at [javax.servlet.ServletException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074611/javax-servlet-servletexception-hv000030-no-validator-could-be-found-for-type) I just want to let clear that this is happening not only with **Integers** but also with **Dates** and maybe for we-dont-know how many other types.

I agree with the statement of trying to understand the annotations before just using them but I also say that we don't have enough documentation for this.